# How to calculate a good background for a small image? (procedural background)

Tags: color, logo, icon, design-principles, procedural-art

I want to *frame* favicons. A size of a favicon is usually 16x16 (could be bigger). The frame would be 160x100. Favicons have different shapes and colors (I don't know ahead of time what favicons look like), and I'd like to compute a good enough background. Could be plain color, could include stripes/patterns.

There are naive ways to do that (compute dominant color and derive background color with good contrast), but I'm wondering if there would any smarter way to build a nice background.

Think about Chrome's new tab page, but instead of screenshots, framed favicons:

[image: Chrome's new tab page]

Some favicons for reference:

[image: some favicons for reference]

Example of naive framing (colors chosen manually):

[image: Example of naive framing]

Comment: Welcome Paul. That's possible for sure, but depends on your programming skills. My first idea would be to find the main color in the image/icon, lower the transperency of this color and return the result - this should be 5-7 lines in python. But it depends on your idea. Note: You could also try using processing.

Comment: I'm looking for ideas/algorithms/papers. Implementation is not an issue.

Comment: I see now that this question is brainstorming/idea gathering for a specific project or a request for free work. This site is suited for answers to general design problems, not ideas or work that is specific to one project.